# Chef server : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "opscode-pgsql"

Tags: chef-infra

I am working on installing chef server on my local system. I already have postgresql installed running on port 5432. When I try to reconfigure chef server, I am getting the error mentioned below. What am I doing wrong? Note I don't have the opscode-psql password, I can change it, but I don't know what kind of effect that would have on current installation. Plus the installer is not even asking me for a password.

I tried editing pg_hba.conf to change local from peer to md5, but that also didn't help.

Error log :

```
================================================================================
    Error executing action `create` on resource 'private_chef_pg_database[opscode-pgsql]'
    ================================================================================

    PG::ConnectionBad
    -----------------
    FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "opscode-pgsql"
    FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "opscode-pgsql"

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 7 resources updated in 55 seconds
[2019-05-03T10:08:13+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2019-05-03T10:08:13+05:30] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2019-05-03T10:08:13+05:30] FATAL: PG::ConnectionBad: private_chef_pg_database[opscode-pgsql] (private-chef::postgresql line 129) had an error: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "opscode-pgsql"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "opscode-pgsql"
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I was running a local instance of Postgresql on port-5432 for another project, conflicting the /opt/opscode/postgresql-96. As soon as I change port for Postgresql for my local instance, and restarted the system, it started working fine.